# operator= for mismatched types

Tags: c++, class, return, operator-overloading

I have the code below where I am trying to create an operator= for my class and a char. The class has a constructor for the char.

It when I call the = operator it will go into the class and assign the class b correctly, but when it returns the byte1 isn't updated. I'm not sure why that would be.

Part of my class:

```
Byte operator=(unsigned char lhs)
{
    Byte b(lhs);
    return b;
}

int main()
{
    unsigned char c1{ 'a' };
    Binary::Byte byte1;
    byte1 = c1;
}
```

Comment: We can't debug your program with "part of your class" :-)

Comment: The problem is that `operator=` is not mutating `*this`. You're creating a new `Byte` object in `operator=`, not modifying the one you already have, and the call to `operator=` in `main` throws the new object away (because you don't use the return value of `byte1 = c1`). `operator=` should, as a rule 1) actually *mutate `*this`*, 2) return `Byte&` (`CurrentClass&` in general), 3) always `return *this;`.

Comment: HTNW, Thank you!  This was exactly the problem.

Comment: Somebody please make an answer or delete this question.

Answer (score 0):

As @HTNW said I was failing to return *this. Should be:

```
Byte operator=(unsigned char lhs)

    {
        Byte b(lhs);
        *this = b;
        return *this;
    }
```